# Sort Data in UITableview using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app that I need to support till the original developer comes back.

Basically it has a method that groups the data into sections of `UITableView`.

It all works very nicely and shows the Sections by `DogLocation`.

This is the code I have :

```
-(void)loadSortedData:(NSString*)breedToLoad fieldToSort:(NSString*)sortField
 {

    self.items = [DbUtilities getDogsByBreed:breedToLoad SortField:sortField];

    NSMutableDictionary * theDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for ( Dog * object in self.items )
    {
      NSMutableArray * theMutableArray = [theDictionary objectForKey:object.DogLocation];

      if ( theMutableArray == nil )
      {
        theMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [theDictionary setObject:theMutableArray forKey:object.DogLocation];
      }

      [theMutableArray addObject:object];

    }

    self.sortedMediaItems = [[theDictionary allKeys]   sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

   /* Save `theDictionary` in an instance variable */
   self.theSource = theDictionary;
   [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I call this method in my `ViewDidLoad`  by using following syntax:

```
[self loadSortedData:@"Cattle" fieldToSort:@"DogLocation"];
```

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to call this method by passing a value in the method e.g  so that I can sort it by other fields and not just the DogLocation e.g DogAge,DogPrice .

Could anyone kindly direct me or show me a better way to achieve this instead of writing big if else statement?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `sortField` is always a valid property of `Dog`, you can use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

```
for ( Dog * object in self.items )
{
  id key = [object valueForKey:sortField];
  NSMutableArray * theMutableArray = [theDictionary objectForKey:key];

  if ( theMutableArray == nil )
  {
    theMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [theDictionary setObject:theMutableArray forKey:key];
  }

  [theMutableArray addObject:object];
}
```

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant!! Thank you exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the M13OrderedDictionary, it's based on NSObject not NSDictionary but it does the job required: https://github.com/Marxon13/M13OrderedDictionary